# JWT auth only by key fails after .net upgrade from 6 to 8

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I have a .NET web server with JWT authentication that checks only the signing key. It's used by other (internal) servers that need a fixed token that doesn't expire.

In .NET 6 it worked fine. After upgrading to .NET 8 the requests always return 401 with the error "The signature key was not found".

My authentication config code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer("external", options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(customKey)),
    };
});
```

The JWT payload is minimal. It is signed with the `customKey` and looks something like this:

header:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```

payload:

```
{
  "sub": "100",
  "name": "Another Server",
  "iat": 1626260955,
  "scopes": [
    "scope_1",
    "scope_2"
  ]
}
```

In the logs I get the following message:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[7] external was not authenticated.
Failure message: IDX10517: Signature validation failed. The token's kid is missing. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: 'XzATZhHqoi5EL7v3Ol4N3Sbp9y2ZYmyC60I32Bos-0E'. , KeyId:  '.
Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'.
```

I can't understand what changed in .NET 8 and how to make it work.

Comment: Make sure you are getting the expected data.  Debug in a way that you can ensure you are getting the right customKey from wherever you are getting it, and that the JWT being received is coming in the right place (cookie or Authorization header or other) and that it contains the expected parts.  You can validate the token @ https://jwt.io.

Comment: @JoséRamírez I verified `customKey` holds the right values and like i wrote, that same code works in .NET 6

Comment: Is the token carrying the signature part?  The 3rd and last part.

Comment: added log errors. @JoséRamírez the token includes the signature (a sample token: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMDAiLCJuYW1lIjoiQW5vdGhlciBTZXJ2ZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjYyNjA5NTUsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJzY29wZV8xIiwic2NvcGVfMiJdfQ.nUG24-vrOWe-w78n4IR0R5vpXCmHTRiqK16RME819Js`) and again, the same token & code work in .NET 6 but fails in .NET 8.

Answer (score 0):

switch from `JwtSecurityToken` and `JwtTokenValidators` to `JsonWebToken` and `TokenHandler` in .NET 8.

you can set `JwtBearerOptions.UseSecurityTokenValidators = true`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events

Comment: adding `JwtBearerOptions.UseSecurityTokenValidators = true` did not help. after adding it I got "The signature key was not found" although `IssuerSigningKey` is set. since i'm not using `JwtSecurityToken` and `JwtTokenValidators` this change is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used an external package `jose-jwt` to perform the token authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer("external", options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        SignatureValidator = (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters) =>
        {
            // custom signature validation
            try
            {
                string json = Jose.JWT.Decode(token, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(customKey));
                return new JsonWebToken(token);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your secret key that you use for generating the token and the hash you pass. In .NET 8, they are more stringent, so you should use the recommended character length. Verify if your secret key has the recommended number of characters; if it’s shorter, you’ll encounter the error you mentioned.

HmacSha256: Recommended: 32 characters (256 bits)

HmacSha384: Recommended: 48 characters (384 bits)

HmacSha512: Recommended: 64 characters (512 bits)

Important: Security: It is advisable to use the maximum recommended length for each algorithm for enhanced security.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the above issue after migrating my API from .NET 6 to .NET8. Based of @Alexander Ardila [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78163445/11157443) and some further research, I found out that the key size was the issue.

In CryptoProviderFactory.cs (Nuget : Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens), a minimum key size check was added in 6.30.1. The breaking change as listed [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/rel/7.1.2/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/CryptoProviderFactory.cs#L490).

In my case, the size of the key used to sign the token was less than required key size. Increasing the key size to greater than recommended value solved the issue for me.

This works if you have control over the signing key, but if validating 3rd party keys or maintaining backwards compatibility is a concern, here is a workaround https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52369#issuecomment-1872286954